# PHP preg pattern needed to get required data from html

Tags: php, preg-match

I am reading HTML source of a website and can find a text like below which is indicating product category.

```
"categories\":[{\"code\":\"women-regular-tops-shirtsandblouses\",
```

in above I need to retrieve "women-regular-tops-shirtsandblouses"

Please help me for preg pattern.

//Update

Here is the code I am using

```
$html = url_get_contents("http://www.landmarkshops.com/Baby-%26-Child/Baby-%26-Child/Boys-Clothing/T-Shirts-%26-Vests/Lee-Cooper-Striped-T-shirt/p/GL301-006BLUE-Blue");

$re = '/(?<=categories"\:\[\{"code"\:").*?(?=\")/';

preg_match($re, $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

But it's not working. Please advise :) @someOne

Comment: Are you sure there is the **not** any `\ `  before the first `"`?!

Comment: Not sure what going on with escaping double quotes but this looks like json string. In which case you should be able extract values using `json_decode()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: @Ulver And may be it's JavaScript!!

Answer (score 0):

The required string is in between `categories":[{"code":"` and `"`, so you may simply use a "positive lookbehind" `(?<=)`, and a "positive lookahead" `(?=)`, to detect the two ends, and the non-greedy any-character match (`.*?`) to capture the string:

```
<?php
$re = '/(?<=categories\\\"\:\[\{\\\"code\\\"\:\\\").*?(?=\\\")/';
$str = '\"categories\":[{\"code\":\"babyandchild-babyandchild-boysclothing-tshirt\",'; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
//output: babyandchild-babyandchild-boysclothing-tshirt
```

Comment: It was even better now :) !

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen "_was_" ?!!

Comment: I mean the answer was now better after explanation :) (Instead of only code)

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen So, what you mean is: "**is**" ;) _the answer **is** now better..._

Comment: lol, I never concentrate on **grammer** and i do concentrate on the **syntax** and i agree with you, I should have used **The answer is now better** \

Comment: @someOne The above code in working, but when I'm changing the $str as below it's not working, can you check please ?  
$str = url_get_contents("http://www.landmarkshops.com/Baby-%26-Child/Baby-%26-Child/Boys-Clothing/T-Shirts-%26-Vests/Lee-Cooper-Striped-T-shirt/p/GL301-006BLUE-Blue");

Comment: @HamidJoukar _below!!_ where?!

Comment: @HamidJoukar Be more **precise** by providing the string, where you think it doesn't fit your requirements, BTW, it's a 404 err!